# Hidden Double Quotes in Oracle Sql Developer Application

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

We are getting hidden double quotes for multiline char column values in Oracle sql application. How to fix this problem? Can some one help us on this?

Example:

"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBCC"

Comment: How you derived that there are hidden double quotes? If you copy from the result of the query(multiline value) then by default, SQL Developer uses Double quotes as the wrapper for each column value. It doesn't mean that there is a double quote in actual data.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior of SQL Developer.

Whenever you copy the data from the result of the query and the value is a multiline value then it uses the double quote as a wrapper to the value but it doesn't mean that there are double quotes in the actual data.

See this:

**SQLPLUS**

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;

CUSTOMER_ID CUSTOMER_NAME
----------- --------------------------------------------------
          1 tejash
```

Copy pasting the result from the SQL Developer:

**SQL Developer**

```
1   tejash
```

Now, Let's add some multiline value in the CUSTOMER_NAME column.

**SQLPLUS**

```
SQL> INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS VALUES
  2  (2,
  3  'TEJASH
  4  SO
  5  EXAMPLE');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;

CUSTOMER_ID CUSTOMER_NAME
----------- --------------------------------------------------
          1 tejash
          2 TEJASH
            SO
            EXAMPLE

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

Copy pasting the result from the SQL Developer:

**SQL Developer**

```
1   tejash
2   "TEJASH
SO
EXAMPLE" -- wrapped in double quotes
```